# How can I write this code with jQuery syntax?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am still new in js and maybe the question is very simple but still I need help. This is a working js example from w3c, which i am trying to implement in my simple site. I want to turn it from plain js to jQuery syntax mostly with educational purpose but have some problems to do it. Another thing i would like to ask is why is [0] given to the variable current (i.e. the clicked number) in the w3c example? I did not catch the logic. 
Thank you!

First the code in js:

```
var btnContainer =  document.getElementById("pages");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("numb");
  for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";    
});
```

And in jquery... obviously with mistakes : ( :

```
var btnContainer = $('#pages');
var btns = $('.numb');
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    $(btns[i]).on('click', function() {
      var current = $('.active');
      current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
      this.className += 'active';   
    });
}
```

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Comment: `var btnContainer = $('#pages');
var btns = $('.numb');` is already different - you'll include all `.numb` even outside `#pages` ... so ... `var btns = $('#pages .numb');` is one solution

Comment: Or `var btnContainer = $('#pages');
var btns = $('.numb', btnContainer);` to limit btns to inside the btncontainer collection.

Comment: Bear in mind that there are a number of errors/assumptions in the original!

Answer (score 0):

You're already storing the reference for the buttons on

> var btns = $('.numb');

So when you add the 'onClick' function, just call the variable, like this:

> btns[i].on('click', function() {
>   ...
>   }

Answer (score 0):

```
// var btnContainer = $('#pages');
// var btns = $('.numb');
$('#pages').on('click', '.numb', function(){
    console.log( this ); // you will get the current element here
    // write your code herer
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do it in pure jQuery is this:

```
// Select all the elements which are children of `#pages` and have class `numb` assigned
$('#pages .numb')
  // Bind click event handler on all of the selected elements
  .click(function() {
    // Remove the class `active` from the element(s) which have this class assigned
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    // Assign the class `active` to the clicked `.numb` element
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you for the answers! Yes, I realized that we do not need this var current which is in the js code. The methods .removeClass and .addClass are enough. And it works! Tthanks ( :

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var btnContainer = $('#pages');
var btns = $('.numb');
    btns.on('click', function() {
        $('.active').removeClass('active'); // OR
        btns.removeClass('active') // removes active class from all btns 
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you did a fine job translating that to jQuery yourself in the question. I haven't tried it out yet because I am in the middle of something else but from a cursory reading or two, it looks just fine. You don't need anything else. jQuery simply is a set of functions that *mostly* allows easy document (object model) access.

The reason the variable `current` is indexed as `current[0]` is because `current` represents *all the elements that have the class name `active`* and since there may be more than one such element, the selector `var current = $('.active');` returns an array of elements (actually of jQuery objects but that's an implementation detail).

Your code is then trying to do something to only the first such element that has the classname `active`. May be that's because the author knows that there's only one such element or he really wants to only affect the first such element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .each function of jquery for this

Example :- btns.each(function(){
                      })
And each element u can acces inside braces by using $(this) .

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#pages').on('click', '.numb', function(){
 $('#pages .numb').removeClass('active');
 $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
#pages li{
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   list-style: none;
   text-align: center;
}
.active{
   line-height: 20px;
   background: blue;
   color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="pages">
     <li class="numb">1</li>
     <li class="numb active">2</li>
     <li class="numb">3</li>
     <li class="numb">4</li>
     <li class="numb">5</li>
</ul>
```